# Use select into statement in sql

Tags: database, sql-server-2008

I use SQL Server 2008.
I have a database (Database1) that has one table (Table1) and I want copy the data of this table to another table (Table2) that it is in another database (Database2).
How to I can write the "SELECT INTO" statement.
It is noteworthy that Table2 is exist in database2 and it has saveral keys and index.
Thanks alot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply;

```
insert into database2.dbo.table2 (f1, f2, fN)
  select f1, f2, fN 
  from database1.dbo.table1
  where x = y
```

Comment: Note that the Table2 is exist in database2 and when I test your answer, I get this Error:"Msg 2601, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Table2' with unique index 'Table_Index'.
The statement has been terminated."

Comment: That means your trying to insert a column from the destination table that has a value that already exists in the corresponding column in the target table, and that target column has been created as *unique*.
So your options are; don't insert rows where that value exists, delete the row in the destination table first, or create a new value for that column that wont conflict.